# Sum of Gaussian Variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let's say I know $X$ is a Gaussian variable.
Moreover, I know $Y$ is a Gaussian variable and $Y=X+Z$.

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent.
How can I prove that $Y$ is a Gaussian random variable if and only if $Z$ is a Gaussian R.V.?

It's easy to show the other way around ($X$ and $Z$ are orthogonal and normal, hence create a Gaussian vector hence any linear combination of the two is a Gaussian variable).

Thanks

Comment: The equation is essentially symmetric. I don't see what the issue is, you seem to already have it reasoned out.

Comment: Use whatever method you used to prove sum of two Gaussian is a Gaussian to prove Z = Y-X.

Comment: I made a mistake and said they are all Independent. I only know X and Z are independent. Hence it's not a Symmetric case.
Sorry and thank you.

Comment: @Drazick: You need to clarify further. You said you know 'Y' is a Gaussian variable, then you asked us to prove a fact about 'Y' being a Gaussian variable

Comment: @This question isn't easy. If X and Z are independent, then it X+Z and X will only be independent in very unusual and specific circumstances and so we won't be able to use the rule about linear combinations of Gaussians

Comment: @Casebash, I wrote Y=X+Z. X~Normal. Now prove Y is Normal iff Z is Normal. One direction (The one I'm interested in) is given Y~Normal, X~Normal, X, Z are independent, Y=X+Z prove that Z is Normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question: given that X and Z are independent, X is Gaussian (I'll use "normal"), and Y = X+Z, prove that Y is normal iff Z is normal. Right? As you observed, one direction is easy: *if* Z is normal, then so is Y=X+Z. So for the other direction, assume that Y is normal. We need to prove that is Z normal too.

Perhaps there's an even easier way, but it's straightforward to use [characteristic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29), which completely characterise distributions. Because X and Z are independent,

$ \varphi_Y(t) = E[e^{itY}] = E[e^{it(X+Z)}] = E[e^{itX}]E[e^{itZ}]$, and so,
$ \varphi_Z(t) = E[e^{itZ}] = E[e^{itY}]/E[e^{itX}] $

This means that Z has exactly the right characteristic function for a normal variable, and hence it's normal.

---

More interestingly and much more generally, there is a theorem of Cramer (e.g. see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=B7Ch-c2G21MC&pg=PA205&dq=cramer+theorem)) which says that if X and Z are independent and X+Z is normally distributed, then both X and Z are!

Comment: Cramer is just what I was looking for! Thank You! Is there a place with different proofs of it?

Comment: Note that you don't need Cramer's theorem for the question you asked: what I gave in my answer is a proof. For the more general case answered by Cramer's theorem, I don't know of any good reference online, but it's usually proved using characteristic functions, as I used above. (I haven't seen an actual proof myself; it may be hard.)

Comment: A readable proof of the Cramer thorem is in the book of Michel Loeve Probability Theory, 3rd ed, Van Nostrand 1963